# How to increase frequency of a repetive animated movement?

Tags: animation

following setup: Blender 2.79 freshly downloaded from builder.blender.org
on Linux (GENTOO) using Cycles.

In a animation I have a character using a saw to cut wood. In a fast movement
the character pushes the the saw away from him/herself and then pull it more
slowing to him/herself.

I animated one movement manually
So far so nice.

One push/pull will not cause anything serious.... ;)

Now the problem:
a) This push/pull movement should be repeated many times.
b) The movement should become faster and faster.
c) I dont want to animate every single push/pull manually.
( d) I got headaches while searching for a neat solution.)

Repeating a movement is not that problem. But anymating the flow
of time over THE WHOLE THING is a problem for me.

How can I acchieve this?

Comment: One way might be to just duplicate the keyframes in the "Dope Sheet" editor. You can change the 3D viewport to "Dope Sheet" and easily move around and copy keyframes with "G" and "shift+D" respectively. That being said, I think there is a better way using the NLA editor, but I'm not a competent or experienced animator.

Comment: After taking a quick peek at the NLA editor, if you open the "N" panel, there is a repeat slider near the bottom which will repeat a set of keyframes. I would find a tutorial though on the NLA editor to understand this better.

Comment: I tried this before: For one linear not repeated NLA-stripe you can add a modifier to non-linear time flow, which speeds up animated movements of that certain stripe. The time curve is part of that certain stripe. Repeating the stripe will repeat the non-linear time flow also. Therefore you will not get an increase in push/pulls *over the whole* animation but each push/pull seperately.

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution myself.
Steps to perform:

- Animate one motion manually. This motion will be repeated and speed
  up in later steps.
- For the NLA strip created that way set the count of repeats in the
  N-key panel.
- In the timeline set the start and end to the first frame and to the
  last frame of the NLA-strip including all repetition.
- Deselect all strips in the NLA editor.
- Only Select the NLA strip in question.
- Now bake the animation. I choose "object" to be baked. This can take
  quite some time.
- The result is an additional strip, which includes the complete
  animation as it had been animated by hand frame by frame.
- Now it is possible to animate the flow of time of this newly created
  strip easily.
- Disable the the original strip (the one with the repetition modifier
  set). You can use this as an backup for later modifications.
- Play the animation.

This is one possible solution, which leads to what I wanted. I am sure, there will be other options to fine tune the result and especially speed up the baking time.

Comment: Oh, I see. That's very useful. I missed the part about time scaling.